# Shiny slider inputs: show a second scale

Tags: shiny

I have values in my data that use different units, and I need to retain the units for what the user sees even though there is a linear conversion between them.

I have a slider input that works as a filter for displaying the data that is <= the slider value.

Is there any way to have a single slider that displays one scale in ticks above the slider, and the other scale in ticks below the slider?  (I only need the value of one of them since I can convert in the background, so this is purely a display thing).